# Which google map API is used for this mouse over make selected region

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, amcharts

Which google map API is used to render the mouse over region selection on map? I have attached an image of the mouse over event. See the darker portion. On mouse over different regions are automatically selected. Here is the site that implemented that feature:[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tYxG.png)

link :http://www.squareyards.com/pune-map-real-estate/micromarket

Answer (score 0):

There's a link at the foot of the map:

https://www.amcharts.com/javascript-maps/

It's not using Google Maps.

Comment: yes its am-chart but how can i implement that, i want city wise and in there document they give only country and state wise..so plz can you help me in that

Comment: @GaneshDeshmukh If you've got a specific problem with your code, feel free to ask that as a new question.